# Bianchi classification of 3-dim Lie algebras and Euclidean space

Tags: differential-geometry

Wikipedia's article about the eight geometries proposed by Thurston for 3-manifolds state that the 3-dimensional Euclidean space $E^3$

> can be modeled as a left invariant metric on the Bianchi groups of type I or VII$_0$.

These two Bianchu types have drastically different metrics. How is it possible that $E^3$ belongs to these two types?

Comment: I edited it, hope it is clearer.

Comment: Here is the exact statement from this page:"Most Thurston geometries can be realized as a left invariant metric on a Bianchi group. However $S^2 × \Bbb R$ cannot be, Euclidean space corresponds to two different Bianchi groups, and there are an uncountable number of solvable non-unimodular Bianchi groups, most of which give model geometries with no compact representatives." So you see, we can realise it in quite different ways, even not at all, or with two types, or with infinitely many types. So, why not?

Comment: My question is more about why $E^3$ admits those two basic types. I mean, what is special about it that allows it to be modeled in those two Bianchi types?